# Cos'è (o era) un "quaderno di bella"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> In quei giorni, secondo le direttive superiori, essa vergava a grandi caratteri sulla lavagna, quale esercizio di scrittura per i suoi scolaretti di terza: 
>         «Copiare tre volte sul quaderno di bella le seguenti parole del Duce: 
>              *Levate in alto, o legionari, le insegne, il ferro e i cuori, a salutare, dopo quindici secoli, la riapparizione dell’Impero sui colli fatali di Roma!* 
>                               
>                      
>              
>                   
>                           
>       *Mussolini*».

Mi chiedo cosa fosse questo "quaderno di bella". Me lo potreste spiegare? Ho cercato alla voce "bello" in alcuni dizionari, ma ci sono tante accezioni che non riesco a vedere se ce n’è qualcuna a cui possa corrispondere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando si andava a scuola in passato ed in effetti anche quando ci andavo io, si usava scrivere i compiti prima sul quaderno di brutta (copia) e poi si ricopiava tutto sul quaderno di bella.

La voce di Treccani per [bella](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bella/) che si addice al contesto da te citato è la seguente:

> 2. Bella copia, stesura definitiva di uno scritto: *mettere in b.; ricopiare in bella.*

Ancora da Treccani per [copia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/copia2/):

> *Bella c.* (o, meno com., *c. al pulito*), la stesura definitiva di uno
>   scritto, contrapposta alla *brutta c.*, cioè la prima stesura,
>   provvisoria, sulla quale si eseguono correzioni e cancellature. In
>   paleografia e in filologia si dice che un codice manoscritto è copia
>   di un altro, quando è esemplato su di esso;

La bella copia era quindi la stesura definitiva del compito che poi veniva valutata dall'insegnante.

Comment: Non avevamo il *bianchetto* che adoperano oggi (sbagliando, secondo me).

Comment: @egreg: Non conoscevo questo vocabolo. Qui lo chiamamo "Tipp-Ex" che infatti è un [marchio commerciale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipp-Ex).

Comment: @Charo “Sbianchettare” è il verbo correlato.

Comment: Sospetto che la *bella copia* esista ancora nella scuola italiana (e ahimé anche il bianchetto, che io non ho mai usato, ma che era molto diffuso ai miei tempi...)

Comment: @Charo *bianchetto* è anche un piccolo bicchiere di vino bianco :)) oppure il novellame di pesce (azzurro, credo).